# Replacing multiple tokens with other strings

Tags: c#, replace

I am translating FoxPro to C# and am having a hard time understanding how I can split a variable. My body has words that need to be swapped that are within "~". So for example, "~this~". Is there a C# equivelent to FoxPro's At()? Code below:

```
lnxx = At("~",lc_body,1)
        If lnxx = 0
            *--paste rest into new body
            lc_newbody = lc_newbody + lc_body
            Exit
        Endif

        *--get ending one
        lnyy = At("~",lc_body,2)



        *--get string out
        lc_string = Substr(lc_body,lnxx,lnyy-lnxx+1)


        *--remove ~
        lc_string = Strtran(lc_string,"~","")


        *--get part to ~, past in new one
        If lnxx>1
            lc_substring = Substr(lc_body,1,lnxx-1)
            lc_newbody = lc_newbody + lc_substring
            *-cut to second ~
            lc_body = Substr(lc_body,lnyy+1,5000)
        Else
            *--it starts with ~, handle this case
            ***newbody is blank
            lc_newbody = ""
            *-cut to second ~
            lc_body = Substr(lc_body,lnyy+1,5000)
        Endif
```

Comment: best to forget that (horrible) thing and rewrite in idiomatic C#, chances are you can do all this in a single / two lines of C# code. What do you really need to do?

Comment: For example, instead of iterating the string and checking for `~` you will use `myString.Split('~');`

Comment: Let's say my string is "Hello, ~CONTACT~. Please respond." I need CONTACT so that I can replace it with the actual contact name. Sometimes it can be ~*CONTACT~ so I will need the asterisk as well. Whatever is within the "~" I need to replace and write the new string message.

Comment: You are doing token replacement?  Eg. Hello ~CONTACT~ becomes Hello Bob Smith?

myString.Replace("~CONTACT~", "Bob Smith");

Done.

If it is more complex, use Regex.Replace. Replacing tokens using Substring and IndexOf should never need to to happen.

Edit: The function you are looking for in C# is IndexOf(), but there are far better ways to do this.

Comment: It's not always CONTACT. I need to replace what is within "~" then switch case depending on what the word is.

Comment: Agree 100% with @DVK, OP, better google "C# replace substring" or things like that and do it in a C# way. It's been 30 years since that foxpro stuff... things just MIGHT have changed a little bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# can do a lot more in a lot less space. The language is jam-packed with utility functions.

I've never used Foxpro myself, ever in fact, but I think I understand the above code based on the comments and documentation I've found online. As @HighCore suggested, idiomatic C# will give you much more readable & maintainable code.

This particular segment you've shown can be expressed simply as this:

```cs
var parts = lc_body.Split(new[] { '~' }, 3);

if (parts.Length == 1)
{
  lc_newbody += lc_body;
  return; // <-- Is this what the Foxpro 'Exit' statement is doing?
}
else // We assume parts.Length == 3, as that is what the original code did
{
  // If lc_body starts with ~, then lc_newbody is cleared, otherwise we append the first part.
  if (parts[0] != "")
    lc_newbody += parts[0];
  else
    lc_newbody = "";

  lc_string = parts[1];

  lc_body = parts[2];
}
```

Some nuances to explain:

- The `.Split` method can be given any number of characters to split upon. This code passes in an array of just one character. C# can actually build that array for you if you don't need any other parameters (e.g. `path.Split('/', '\\')`), but we're using a second parameter here.
- That second parameter, the "3", gives an upper limit on the parts into which the string will be split. if you omit it, it'll keep splitting until the entire string is split. Since this code seems to assume there may be further tildes later in the string, though, I set this to 3 so that the `lc_body` variable can be set to the remainder of the string for further processing.
- The `.Split` method will return parts even if they are empty; splitting `"~foo~bar"` on `'~'` will produce an array of three strings where the first one is `""`, the empty string.

To critique this, beyond noting that it will produce an error if the string has an odd number of tildes in it, I notice that if `lc_body` does not contain any tilde characters, then `lc_string` does not get cleared, and `lc_body` is not cleared, even though it is apparently being consumed into `lc_newbody` in its entirely. I'm guessing there's more code surrounding this -- a loop, and code that actually makes use of the value of in `lc_string`.

You should also look up things like `string`'s `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` functions, the `string.Join` and `string.IsNullOrEmpty` static methods, `string.Format` for putting a complex series of pieces together, and so on. If this code is doing a lot of string manipulation, they'll come in very handy. :-)

---

**EDIT**: Based on your description in comments, you could simplify this entire thing quite considerably with code like the following. It works on the principle that if you have multiple insertion points, splitting the entire string on the tilde character will mean that every *other* element in the array will be an insertion point -- for instance, `"Plain text ~first~ more text ~second~ a bit more"` will give the array `{ "Plain text ", "first", " more text ", "second", " a bit more" }`. Thus, you can go through that array and do the replacement on every second element only, and then put the results all back together:

```
string DoReplacements(string body, Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
{
  string[] parts = body.Split('~');

  // Start on the second element, with index 1, and increment the index by 2.
  for (int i = 1; i < parts.Length; i += 2)
    replacements.TryGetValue(parts[i], out parts[i]);

  // Put it all back together.
  return string.Concat(parts);
}
```

Comment: The response by @Erik Philips is also excellent, but does require that your insertion points look like "{0}", "{1}", and so on. If you want to use named values, then you have to do a bit of legwork, either something like my edited answer above, or something that translates named insertion points to the numbers that `string.Format` can use.

Comment: could you show a working example of DoReplacements in dotnetfiddle.net, please?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are experiencing an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.
>
> That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

Onto your problem at hand:

> My body has words that need to be swapped that are within "~". So for example, "~this~".

Which really has nothing to do with *HOW* it is solved with any available methods in FoxPro.

To replace a string value within another string value you simply use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jcTfcm) and Code:

using System;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var originalText = "~this~ is a sentence that contains ~this~ more than once.";

        Console.WriteLine(originalText);

        var replacedText = originalText.Replace("~this~", "~that~");

        Console.WriteLine(replacedText);
    }
}
```

Result:

> ~this~ is a sentence that contains ~this~ more than once.
>
> ~that~ is a sentence that contains ~that~ more than once.

If you have control over the source text, then I would highly recommend you use [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hoczXK) and Code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var originalText = "{0} is a sentence that contains {0} more than once.";

        Console.WriteLine(originalText);

        var replacedText = string.Format(originalText, "~that~");

        Console.WriteLine(replacedText);
    }
}
```

Result:

> {0} is a sentence that contains {0} more than once.
>
> ~that~ is a sentence that contains ~that~ more than once.

The great thing about `String.Format()` is that if there are no substitutions found to replace, there is no exception, it just doesn't replace anything.  This solves the problem of having multiple replace statements, and instead relies only on a single method:

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nf6qEE) and Code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var originalText = "{0} should be [this], and {2} should be [that], and there should be no [thus]";

        Console.WriteLine(originalText);

        var replacedText = string.Format(originalText, "this", "thus", "that");

        Console.WriteLine(replacedText);
    }
}
```

Result:

> {0} should be [this], and {2} should be [that], and there should be no [thus]
>
> this should be [this], and that should be [that], and there should be no [thus]

Answer (score 0):

[`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you the position of a character in a string. [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) will split a delimited string into a series of strings.

Comment: please give an example of how this will work with the code above?